# What is the need for signed and unsigned characters in C

Tags: c

What is the need for signed and unsigned characters in C?

Is there some special reason for having a signed and unsigned char in C? Or was it simply added for completeness so that the compiler does not have to check the data type before adding signed/unsigned modifier?

I am not asking about signed and unsigned variables. My doubt is about the special cases where an unsigned character variable will not be sufficient such that you have to depend on a signed character variable.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations

Comment: `I am not asking about signed and unsigned variables`. You've accepted an answer which describes exactly that. Out of curiousity, why did you? I'm also not completely sure what you mean to ask if that is what you were looking for.

Comment: I wanted to find out a problem where you specifically need signed/unsigned character variables. Since I didn't get any answer to that effect, I conclude that there may not be such a problem after all. Hence the answer is accepted. Why waste others time :). But if you could provide an example problem I will be most obliged.

Comment: `signed char` is usually used for text representation. Just by convention. `unsigned char` is considerably better when processing raw data and you need to handle some math on top of it. For example, when you expand value 128 to int, unsigned char will stay 128 (0x80). Signed char would become -1 (0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFF80), which might be something you dont want

Comment: Thank You. Please post it as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `char` can be either signed or unsigned depending on what is most efficient for the underlying hardware. The keywords `signed` and `unsigned` allow you to explicitly specify that you want something else.

A quote from the C99 rationale:

> Three types of `char` are specified: `signed`, plain, and `unsigned`. A plain `char` may be represented as either signed or unsigned depending upon the implementation, as in prior practice. The type `signed char` was introduced in C89 to make available a one-byte signed integer type on those systems which implemented plain `char` as `unsigned char`. For reasons of symmetry, the keyword `signed` is allowed as part of the type name of other integer types.

Answer (score 2):

**Information #1:** `char` in C is just a small `int`, which uses 8 bits.

**Information #2:** Difference between `signed` and `unsigned`, is that one bit in the representation is used as the sign bit for a `signed` variable.

**Information #3:** As a result of (#2), `signed` variables hold different ranges (-128 to 127, in `char` case) compared to `unsigned` (0 to 255 in `char` case).

**Q-A #1:** why do we need `unsigned`?

In most cases (for instance representing a pointer) we do not need signed variables. By convention all locations in the memory are exposed to the program as a contiguous array of unsigned addresses.

**Q-A #2:** why do we need `signed`?

Generally, to do signed arithmetic.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using a char to hold numbers, not characters.

So:

signed char gives you at least the -128 to 127 range.
unsigned char gives you at least the 0 to 255 range.

A char is required by standard to be AT LEAST 8 bits, so that is the reason for my saying at least. It is possible for these values to be larger.

Anyway, to answer your question, having a char as unsigned frees the requirement for the first bit to be the 'sign' bit, thus allowing you to hold near double that of a signed char.

Answer (score 0):

The thing you have to understand is that datatype "char" is actually just an integer, typically 8-bits wide. You can use it like any other inter datatype, assuming you respect the reduced value limits. There is no reason to limit "char" to characters.

On a 32/64-bit processor, there is typically no need to use such small integer fields, but on an 8-bit processor such as the 8051, 8-bit integers are no only much faster to process and use less (limited) memory.

Comment: your second paragraph provides incorrect information. Why would 32/64 bit processor have 'no need' to use chars. It still saves memory, and memory access.