# what is the use of signed char and unsigned char

Tags: c, memory

since C language using the char as integer internally(correspondent ASCII is stored). for internal calculation we can use signed and unsigned char.

other than that, any other use??

Comment: I hope you find your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4337217/difference-between-signed-unsigned-char)

Comment: One example: An unsigned char pointer is allowed to alias other types and thereby it can be used to access the bit pattern of the other type.

Comment: @Outlaw : that i saw, any other diffrents?

Comment: ASCII is a common character representation but other have existed around like [EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC) for example

Comment: @SergeBallesta [link](https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Procedures/ASCII-to-EBCDIC-problems-with-ebcdic-format/td-p/102461)

Comment: even though ASCII is not enough to represent the char in other language like Chinese. because char is more. UNICODE is better

Comment: @ShyjuCR: Simply in most implementations, `char` is only 8 bits large so cannot represents all unicode characters. That's the reason why ASCII and other 8 bits charset like the ISO-8859-xx family are still used and why unicode can be encoded (as multi-byte) in UTF-8.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the need for signed and unsigned characters in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15416586/what-is-the-need-for-signed-and-unsigned-characters-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

`signed` and `unsigned` `char` are first and foremost just small integers. Do you need to store a large quantity of small numbers (in the range [-127, +127]¹ or [0, 255])? You can use an array of `signed` or `unsigned` chars and save memory compared to pretty much any other type. That's what is done for e.g. images - a grayscale image is generally stored as an array of `unsigned char` (and an RGB image is generally stored as an array of 3 `unsigned char` components).

The second usage of `char` is for character strings, which you probably already saw; notice that `char` is a distinct type from both `signed char` and `unsigned char`, and its signedness is implementation defined. This is stupid and inconvenient in many situations - and leads to sad stuff such as the mandatory cast to `unsigned char` when calling functions of the `toupper`/`isupper` family.

Finally, `char` & co. are defined as the "underlying storage" of the C abstract machine. `sizeof(char) == 1` by definition, and any type can be aliased through a `(signed|unsigned)? char` pointer to access its underlying bit representation.

---

1. Yes, -127; [-127, +127] is the minimum range allowed for `signed char` by the standard, as it still allows sign and magnitude representation; more realistic, on any real-world machine of this century it will be at least [-128, 127].

Comment: i have an answer for your page [status](https://stackoverflow.com/users/214671/matteo-italia), size_t is big enough to hold amount of data. but in case of int and double their max size is already defined by the compiler(32bit->unsigned int, 64->unsigned long long ).

Comment: @ShyjuCR that doesn't make any sense. `size_t` also has a maximum value

Comment: @ShyjuCR: er... I don't get exactly what you're saying, but no.